# Is there a way I can declare a dependency by value for my properties using JSON SCHEMA?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Let's say we have a simple object like:

{
  "key_1": "value_1",
  "key_2": "value_2"
}

is there a way I can craft my json schema by declaring an inter-key dependency based on their values such that it would NOT ALLOW repetition of `value_1` in `key_2`? I'm using json schema draft-4

DO NOT ALLOW:

{
  "key_1": "value_1",
  "key_2": "value_1"
}

Comment: Is there a finite number of values that may not be repeated? If not, this falls in the realm of “business logic” which is out-of-scope for the JSON Schema Specification and would need to be handled in your application code.

Comment: yea, there's a finite number of values not to be repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: if either the keys and/or values are unknown upfront, this falls in the category "business logic" which is out-of-scope for the JSON Schema Specification and would need to be handled independently.

---

As per your comment, there is a finite number of values (and I assume also of the keys). That means you have a couple of options – even in Draft 4.

#### 1. Using `anyOf` to ensure that all but one key don't have a particular value and finally wrapping it in `allOf` (for each value).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "key_1": { "type": "string" },
    "key_2": { "type": "string" },
    "key_3": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties":{
            "key_1": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } },
            "key_2": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties":{
            "key_1": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } },
            "key_3": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties":{
            "key_2": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } },
            "key_3": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties":{
            "key_1": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } },
            "key_2": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties":{
            "key_1": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } },
            "key_3": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties":{
            "key_2": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } },
            "key_3": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### 2. Using `oneOf` to indicate that either none or exactly one key has a particular value. Doing that for each possible value and finally wrapping it in `allOf`.

Beware the `required` keyword to ensure that the respective key is actually present.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "key_1": { "type": "string" },
    "key_2": { "type": "string" },
    "key_3": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_1": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } },
            "key_2": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } },
            "key_3": { "not": { "enum": ["value_1"] } }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_1": { "enum": ["value_1"] }
          },
          "required": ["key_1"]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_2": { "enum": ["value_1"] }
          },
          "required": ["key_2"]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_3": { "enum": ["value_1"] }
          },
          "required": ["key_3"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_1": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } },
            "key_2": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } },
            "key_3": { "not": { "enum": ["value_2"] } }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_1": { "enum": ["value_2"] }
          },
          "required": ["key_1"]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_2": { "enum": ["value_2"] }
          },
          "required": ["key_2"]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "key_3": { "enum": ["value_2"] }
          },
          "required": ["key_3"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There are probably some more combinations, e.g. listing all allowed value combinations, but you get the idea: for a few keys and values this is manageable but it gets unwieldy rather quickly – assuming you have to maintain this manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution not working against draft-04, I'm using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to test

Comment: You’re right, the `const` keyword was only introduced in Draft 6 as syntactic sugar for `enum` with a single entry. I’ll change the given schemas accordingly.

Comment: @tomshy I've replaced the `const` keyword with `enum` now and confirmed that it works via the mentioned validation website – the basic principle is still the same though.